# Cloud data fusion to sync tables from BigQuery to Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have a use case where I need to sync spanner table with Big Query tables. So I need to update the Spanner tables based on the updated data in Big Query tables. I am planning to using Cloud data fusion for this. But I do not see any example available for this scenario. Any pointers on this?